# widget , call function from option error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In the widget I'm trying to call a function from a property in the options

```
getThing: this._runFunc()
```

but I get an error saying _runFunc()  is not an instance of an object? can you please help?

---

```
 $.widget('my.testW', {
        options:{
            buttons:buttons,
            getThing: this._runFunc() // why wont _runFunc work?
        },
        _create: function () {
                //do things    
                var s = this.options.getThing;

        },
        _runFunc: function (){
            return 'hello world'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `$.widget` call, the `options` object and the anonymous object literal within which it is contained are just parameters to `$.widget`, so `this` refers to whatever `this` was outside the `$.widget` call, and not the newly defined widget.

AFAIK, there's no way to refer to some other element of the same anonymous object literal from within values of that literal.

If you wish to hide your function, you could define your widget thus:

```
(function() {
     function _runFunc() {
          return 'hello world';
     };

     $.widget(..., {
         options: {
             getThing: _runFunc()
         },
         _runFunc: _runFunc;  // if you want to expose this method
     });
 })();
```

where the IIFE encloses the utility function within that scope.